# select all records with multiple category

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out how to select all records that are associated with all categories on a list.

For instance take this DB setup:

```sql
create table blog (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  url varchar(100)
  );
  
create table blog_category (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(50)
  );

create table blog_to_blog_category (
  blog_id integer,
  blog_category_id integer
  );
  
  insert into blog values 
    (1, 'google.com'),
    (2, 'pets.com'),
    (3, 'petsearch.com');
    
insert into blog_category values
  (1, 'search'),
  (2, 'pets'),
  (3, 'misc');
  
insert into blog_to_blog_category values
  (1,1),
  (2,2),
  (3,1),
  (3,2),
   (3,3);
```

I can query on the main table like this:

```sql
select b.*, string_agg(bc.name, ', ') from blog b
join blog_to_blog_category btbc on b.id = btbc.blog_id 
join blog_category bc on btbc.blog_category_id = bc.id
where b.url like '%.com'
group by b.id
```

But lets say I want to only return blogs that have BOTH category 1 & 2 connected with them how do I do that?

This would return just the `petsearch.com` domain as it is only record to have both of those categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Added a check to count the blog_category id (HAVING Clause) and if it is 2 then it should be either 1 or 2 (IN Clause),

```
select b.*, string_agg(bc.name, ', ') from blog b
join blog_to_blog_category btbc on b.id = btbc.blog_id 
join blog_category bc on btbc.blog_category_id = bc.id
where b.url like '%.com' and bc.id in (1,2)
group by b.id
having count(distinct bc.id ) =2
```

Comment: @Guerilla . . . This filters out non-1/2 categories in the results.  Your question does not suggest that you actually want to do that filtering.  That is "3". has both 1 and 2, so it meets your condition, but why wouldn't you want category 3 in the result?

Answer (score 1):

here is one way:

```
select * from blog where id in ( 
select blog_id
from blog_to_blog_category bbc
where blog_category_id in (1, 2)
group by blog_id
having count(distinct blog_category_id) = 2
)
```